# Datatables - stateSave not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use `stateSave` to keep my table data when a user close the application and open in other time of the day.

I've tried to simple initialization, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );
```

And the result for of the hardcoded above is:

[image: table]

Without this code, my table is displayied normally, as u can see:

[image: my normal table]

Anyone knows how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ave found the problem.

The datatable saveState doesn't work with colResize. I just took off the colResize and it began to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Lucas - You can save the state even with colResize or colReorder however, it only saves the state that are part of its native extensions (colReOrder). colResize is a plugin and not native extensions so it wont save its changes.

In both cases, you have call the DataTable savestate explicitly. See below for a sample:

```js
//G_DataTable is the datatable instance.  
// 'column-reorder' event should be binded manually to datatable to listen to those changes.
G_DataTable.on('column-reorder',function(e, settings, defaults){
            G_DataTable.state.save(); // to save the current state explicitly
});
```